# A function is calling itself, without any recursive calls implemented in it

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js

I have this function to get the shops from a mongodb DB.

```
exports.find_shops = function(selector, fields, limit, skip, cb){
    if(typeof fields == 'function'){
        limit = 0
        cb = fields
        fields = {}
        skip = 0
    }
    if(typeof limit == 'function'){
        cb = limit
        limit = 0
        skip = 0
    }
    if(typeof skip == 'function'){
        cb = skip
        skip = 0
    }
    if(typeof selector == 'string'){
        limit = 1
        selector = {_id: new db.bson_serializer.ObjectID(selector)}
    }
    console.log('a')
    Shop.find(selector, fields).limit(limit).toArray(function(err, shops){
        console.log('b')
        if(err){
            throw new Error(err)
        } else {
            if(limit == 1){
                cb(shops[0])
            } else {
                cb(shops)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The output I get in the console looks like

a
b
b

whereas I expect it to be

a
b

Whats wrong here?

EDIT:

```
exports.search = function(products, location, skip, cb){
    if(typeof skip == 'function'){
        cb = skip
        skip = 0
    }
    this.find_shops({
        products: {
            $in: products
        },
        $or: [{
            location: { $near: location , $maxDistance: 2 }
        },
        {
            delivery: -1
        },
        {
            delivery: {$lt: 2}
        }]
        }, {name: 1, location: 1, delivery: 1, products: 1}, 10, skip, function(shops){
            shops.forEach(function(i,shop){
                shops[i] = _.intersect(shop.products, products)
            })
            // now we have the products that user needs from this shop.
            var combos = []
            shops.forEach(function(i,shop1){
                var combo = [i]
                var p = shop1.products
                shops.forEach(function(j,shop2){
                    if(i > j){
                        return
                    } else {
                        var newprod = _.intersect(p,shop2.products)
                        if(newprod.length == shop2.products.length){
                            return
                        } else {
                            p.push(shop2.products)
                            p = _.uniq
                            combo.push(j)
                            if(p.length == products.length){
                                combos.push(combo)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
            cb(combos)
        })
}
```

Comment: You  throw some code without further context at our heads and expect that we should understand it and find a solution?

Comment: Why did you not include the extremely important code from which you **call** this function?

Comment: hi, i apologize for not adding the callee earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the `toArray()` function converts its input into an array, and then passes each element of the array to the closure function in its parameter?

If that's the case, then the result you're seeing could be caused simply by `toArray()` generating an array of two items. That doesn't needs anything to be recursive in any way.

Comment: This is the same syntax I am using in 2 other places, where the toArray function is working as expected.